# How do you pronounce GNOME?

Tags: gnome

Is it like "gnome" [noum] or is it like "genome" ['dʒi:noum]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [GNOME Frequently Asked Questions - How do I pronounce GNOME?](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/astaff/project/aui/html/pronunciation.html):

> GNOME stands for "GNU Network Object Model Environment". GNU stands for "GNU's Not Unix", and has always been officially pronounced "guh-NEW" to minimize confusion. Since GNU is GNOME's first name, GNOME is officially pronounced "guh-NOME".
>
> However, many people pronounce GNOME as just "NOME" (like those short people from legend), nobody will hurt you if you find this pronunciation easier.

Comment: I wonder why that page is on an MIT server instead of on gnome.org. The closest "official" source I could find was GNOME's verified Twitter account: https://twitter.com/gnome/status/1169956747324227585?lang=en

Comment: Hmm. I had always called it gee-gnome and GNU gee-en-yew.